# How to run a set of animations after scrolling 100px down the page?

Tags: jquery, header, navigation, jquery-animate, fixed

I am trying to make a website header become sticky, animate the logo img smaller, and reposition the navigation links once the user scrolls 100px down the page.

Here is what I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#header').addClass('sticky');
        $('#logo img').animate({'width':'200px','top':'-10px'});
        $('#header').animate({'height':'70px'});
        $('#menu_btns ul li').animate({'top':'-24px','left':'-90px'});
        $('#store_links').animate({'top':'-20px','left':'0px'});    

    }
    else {
        $('#header').removeClass('sticky');
        $('#logo img').animate({'width':'287px','top':'0px'});
        $('#header').animate({'height':'116px'});
        $('#menu_btns ul li').animate({'top':'0px','left':'0px'});
        $('#store_links').animate({'top':'0px','left':'0px'});

    }
});
});
```

The problem I'm having is after scrolling down and everything animates, after going back up none of the "else" animations execute.

Comment: have you tried using waypoints?

Comment: @otherDewi Is it possible to run the multiple animations with waypoint? With my current code, i can get the sticky nav to function but as soon as i add in the animations, everything breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding "=" in if condition.

```
$(document).scrollTop() >= 100
```

Have a look at here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCpEh/1/)

Comment: Thanks @SAM this seems to work but only when I set the animation speed to 1 which kind of defeats the purpose of the animation. If I don't set an animation speed, it takes forever to reset after I've scrolled back to the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Search for waypoints.js. it is what you need. An example using waypoints would be

```
var $mainNav = $("header nav");

$mainNav.waypoint(function(direction){

    if(direction==="down"){
        //if the scroll direction is down then fix the nav ul to the top of the screen
        $(this).find('ul').css({position:'fixed', top: 0});
    }else{
        //if the scroll direction is up then position the nav ul back in the document flow
        $(this).find('ul').css({position:'static'});
    }

});
```

The code senses the direction of the scroll then sticks and unsticks the code accordingly.

Waypoints are powerful and allow the programmer to trigger events when the user scrolls to a certain point on a page. Common uses are to make a nav bar stick when it reaches the top of the view port, as per the code snippet above, or triggering animations.

Comment: Is it possible to run the multiple animations with waypoint? With my current code, i can get the sticky nav to function but as soon as i add in the animations, everything breaks.